# OleDbCommand, No value given

Tags: c#, oledbcommand

With an Access table (Customers) and two fields (CustomerID, CustomerName):

```
string queryString = "INSERT INTO Customers (CustomerID, CompanyName)  VALUES (qqq, xyz)";
OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(queryString, connection);
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

results in an error:

> *No value given for one or more required parameters*

Both fields have a text Data Type

Comment: What are qqq and xyz? You need to use a parameterized query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I strongly suspect since you used `qqq` and `xyz` without single quotes, `OleDbCommand` see them as a parameter. That's why it expects some parameter values for both.

Because if they were strings, they would be used with single quotes like;

```
INSERT INTO Customers (CustomerID, CompanyName)  VALUES ('qqq', 'xyz')
```

If they are some variables, and want to add them to your command, you should always use [parameterized queries](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/) to prevent [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.

```
using(OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(conString))
using(OleDbCommand command = _connection.CreateCommand())
{
    command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Customers(CustomerID, CompanyName) VALUES(?, ?)";
    command.Parameters.Add("@p1", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = qqq;
    command.Parameters.Add("@p2", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = xyz;
    connection.Open();
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

And `CustomerID` is a *very* bad name for a character column because as a general `ID` part used for numerical values.

Comment: Thanks for both answers!

Answer (score 1):

You should pass your values to the database engine using a parameterized query

```
string queryString = "INSERT INTO Customers (CustomerID, CompanyName)  VALUES (?,?)";
OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(queryString, connection);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", valueForCustomerIDFIeld)
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p2", valueForComapnyNameFIeld)
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Actually I don't know what the `qqq` and `xyz` are. But embedding them inside the sql string cause them to be considered as parameter placeholders, thus the engine asks for two parameters.

Comment: Unless they are between single quotes, where they would be considered as values. Other than that, parameterized query is the way to go.